# What's the best way to allow communication between packages?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have created two classes:

1. **Verify Title**: it accesses the Facebook page and checks the title of the page.
2. **ScreenShot**: it is responsible for capturing an image when the page title is not as expected.

How can one instantiate **ScreenShot** class inside Verify Title class?

**Key Note**: Both classes are in different packages but within the same java project.

```
public class VerifyTitle {

ExtentReports report;
ExtentTest logger;
WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void verifyBlogTitle() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://pt-br.facebook.com/");
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Facebook"));  
}
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        
        
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ScreenShot {
public static void capturarImagem(WebDriver driver, String NomeDaImagem) {      
    try {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./Imagens/"+NomeDaImagem+".png") );
        System.out.println("Imagem capturada!");
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao capturara a image: WebDriver Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao capturara a image: IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

}

[Class VerifyTitle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLXl6.jpg)

[Class ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DSeN.jpg)

Comment: Do you have import the class  ScreenShot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use import statement for ScreenShot class in the VerifyTitle.java class file.

Comment: how do I import imported? Give me an example based on my class.

Comment: After importing the ScreenShot class, worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that packages are not able to communicate with each other. You can resolve this by simply **importing pkg2 and class ScreenCapture**.

```
 Project/
 ├── pkg1 -> VerifyTitle class public -> import pkg2 and class Screenshot
 └── pkg2 -> ScreenCapture class public
```